# Copy columns into Notepad

Tags: excel, vba, notepad

I have following Excel VBA code to open Notepad and copy Excel columns into Notepad.

```vb
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rDataRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sCellContent As String
    Dim sStringout As String
    Dim lrowData As Long                                        ' XXX Added
  
'   This is worksheet where data is located.
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
  
'   This is where data to be processed is located.
    lrowData = wsSource.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ' XXX Added
    Set rDataRange = wsSource.Range("G40:H" & lrowData)         ' XXX Modified
  
'   Iterate through all source data cells.
    For Each rCell In rDataRange.Columns(1).Cells               ' XXX Loop modified
      
'   Add the cell's content to the full output string
    sStringout = sStringout & rCell.Value & " " & rCell.Offset(, 1).Value & ";"
      
    Next rCell
  
'   Remove trailing semi-colon
    sStringout = Left(sStringout, Len(sStringout) - 1)
  
'   Start Notepad with focus
    Shell "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
    
'   Put the string into the free notepad.
    SendKeys sStringout
```

This copies everything on one line.

The columns **G** and **H** should be copied to two lines.
One for **G** and below for **H**.

It should look like.

```
column G -> mail;policy;E164;VoiceRoutingPolicy;Language;DialPlan
column H -> toto.user@axa.be;UpgradeToTeams;111111111;VRP-GEN-BE-Europe_Zone2;en-US;BE
```

Answer (score 0):

the "easy solution" amending your code is

```
Sub twolines()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim rDataRange1 As Range
    Dim rDataRange2 As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sCellContent As String
    Dim sStringout As String
    Dim lrowData As Long                                        ' XXX Added
  
'   This is worksheet where data is located.
    Set wsSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
  
'   This is where data to be processed is located.
    lrowData = wsSource.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   ' XXX Added
    
    
    Set rDataRange1 = wsSource.Range("G40:G" & lrowData)         ' XXX Modified
    Set rDataRange2 = wsSource.Range("H40:H" & lrowData)         ' XXX Modified
  
'   Iterate through all source data cells.
    For Each rCell In rDataRange1.Cells               ' XXX Loop modified
'   Add the cell's content to the full output string
    sStringout = sStringout & rCell.Value & ";"
    Next rCell
  
'   Remove trailing semi-colon
    sStringout = Left(sStringout, Len(sStringout) - 1)
'   NewLine
    sStringout = sStringout & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
  
    For Each rCell In rDataRange2.Cells               ' XXX Loop modified
'   Add the cell's content to the full output string
    sStringout = sStringout & rCell.Value & ";"
    Next rCell
  
  
'   Remove trailing semi-colon
    sStringout = Left(sStringout, Len(sStringout) - 1)
  
'   Start Notepad with focus
    Shell "C:\windows\system32\notepad.exe", vbNormalFocus
    
'   Put the string into the free notepad.
    SendKeys sStringout
End Sub
```

BUT: some people think "sendkeys" is kind of bad behaviour, as it is hard to control, user can change result by interacting with PC ....

Other possibility would be to write a ready-to-go txt-file with this function:

```
Function write_textfile(pathandname_file As String, text As String)
On Error GoTo Ende
Dim Datei As String
Dim Fnr As Long

    Datei = Mid(pathandname_file, 1, Len(pathandname_file) - 3) & "txt"
    Fnr = FreeFile
    Open Datei For Output As Fnr
Print #Fnr, text
    Close Fnr
    Exit Function

Ende:
End Function
```

by replacing "sendkeys" with  "write_textfile c:\myfile.txt, stringout"